# Runtime error replacing assembly reference ComponentModel.DataAnnotations with Nuget ComponentModel.Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, annotations, nuget

I have a WebAPI project which had an old assembly reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`

I am trying to add some logging and the nuget package for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`has a dependency on `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll` which conflicts with the assembly reference.

After removing the assembly reference the project still compiles just fine, but at runtime I get an exception when I reach code with annotations:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations,
> Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried installing the nuget package for `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`, but I still get the same error.

**How do I replace the assembly reference to ComponentModel.DataAnnotations with the nuget package?**

Comment: Try to add these node in `web.config` file: `<configuration><runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> <dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  culture="neutral" />  
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0"  newVersion="4.2.1.0"/></dependentAssembly> </assemblyBinding>   </runtime> </configuration> `

Comment: Besides, open CMD as administrator and then type `cd xxx(path of the System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll,usually under the folder called packages of the solution folder)`  then type `gacutil /i System.ComponentModel.Annotations`. Delete `bin` and `obj` and then rebuild the project again.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thank you very much. Unfortunately your suggestion did not change anything. I did not even have System.ComponentModel.Annotations in the bin folder

Comment: Did it exist under `<solutiion folder>\packages`?

Comment: The package did indeed exist under '<solutiion folder>\packages'.
However, the gacutil command did not work (I also tried going inside the annotations folder)

Comment: Then try to gacutil the dll from the folder.

Comment: Should I run gacutil for all the folders? I have 14 folders in the lib folder under the System.componentmodel.Annotations folder

Comment: and should I delete the packages folder after running the command?

Comment: Just gacutil the dll which your project references. You can unload your  project and enter the `xxx.csproj` file. Check the `hintpath` of  the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`. It will show you which path of the dll it references. And then gacutil  that dll.

Comment: It is no need at all.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :) Unfortunately I can't actually add the dll from the hintpath I originally included. gacutil simply fails with "Failure adding assembly to the cache:   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."